# Making Implemetation More Generic With Scala and Cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have this in-memory implementation of a simple Cache in Scala using cats effects.

Here is my trait:

```
trait Cache[F[_], K, V] {
  def get(key: K): F[Option[V]]
  def put(key: K, value: V): F[Cache[F, K, V]]
}

import cats.effect.kernel.Async

case class ImmutableMapCache[F[_]: Async, K, V](map: Map[K, V]) extends Cache[F, K, V] {
  override def get(key: K): F[Option[V]] =
    Async[F].blocking(map.get(key))

  override def put(key: K, value: V): F[Cache[F, K, V]] =
    Async[F].blocking(ImmutableMapCache(map.updated(key, value)))
}

object ImmutableMapCache {
  def empty[F[_]: Async, K, V]: F[Cache[F, K, V]] =
    Async[F].pure(ImmutableMapCache(Map.empty))
}
```

Is this a good enough implementation? I'm restricting my effect to Async. Can I make it even more generic to work with other effect types in my ImmutableMapCache?

What other pitfalls are there with my approach?

EDIT:

Is this a better implementation where I wrap the Map in a Cats Ref context?

```
import cats.effect.{Ref, Sync}
import cats.syntax.all._

class SimpleCache[F[_]: Sync, K, V] extends Cache[F, K, V] {
  private val cache: Ref[F, Map[K, V]] = Ref.unsafe[F, Map[K, V]](Map.empty)

  override def put(key: K, value: V): F[Unit] = cache.update(_.updated(key, value))

  override def get(key: K): F[Option[V]] = cache.get.map(_.get(key))
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an Immutable Map for something like a cache which you would want to support high performance mutations ? Also... if are you using `blocking` in the `Async` context then why even use Async ? In creating an Immutable Cache... you are likely to be updating the variable holding the cache to the new cache on every put... but this is opening the doors for race conditions when accessed by multiple threads. You are doing a lot of things which you would absolutely not want from a Cache  implementation.

Comment: `Ref` uses `AtomicReference` underneath so it is safe to use in multithreaded context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the right answer is not to reinvent the wheel, and just use a library that already does all this, like [**mules**](https://github.com/davenverse/mules).

However, for the sake of learning, let's take a look to some of the things you could improve.

1. Interface. Especially `put`

```scala
def put(key: K, value: V): F[Cache[F, K, V]]
```

If putting a new value in the `Cache` returns a new one, it means it is immutable, if it is immutable there is no need for effects, meaning it is just a simple `Map`.
You want your `put` to mutate something; but in a concurrent-safe way. So it could actually be used to share data between different `Fibers`. Thus, `put` should be defined like this:

```scala
def put(key: K, value: V): F[Unit]
```

2. Creation. Since a `Cache` is a mutable state, its creation must be an effect as well; like your original example but unlike your attempt with `Ref`

```scala
def empty[F[_], K, V]: F[Cache[F, K, V]]
```

3. Implementation. Your intuition was right, we want to use a mutable reference to an immutable `Map`. Now, in order to make it concurrent safe, we need to either look the access to it, or use a CAS loop. **cats-effect** provides both options: `AtomicCell` and `Ref` respectively. In this case is better to just use a CAS loop so we go with `Ref`

```scala
object Cache {
  def empty[F[_], K, V]: F[Cache[F, K, V]] =
    Ref[F].of(Map.empty[K, V]).map { ref =>
      new Cache[F[_], K, V] {
        override def get(key: K): F[Option[V]] =
          ref.get.map(map => map.get(key))

        override def put(key: K, value: V): F[Unit] =
          ref.update(map => map.updated(key, value))
      }
    }
}
```

4. The constraints, the above code needs a constraint on `F` to actually work. But actually, we don't need all the `Async` power, but rather just `Concurrent`, since all we need is to create a `Ref` :)

```scala
def empty[F[_] : Concurrent, K, V]: F[Cache[F, K, V]] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So with that addition of the empty method, I can get rid of the local val cache that I create using Ref. Correct?

Comment: @joesan yes, especially because that one was _"technically"_ wrong :)

Comment: Ok, so that empty method definition goes in the trait. Correct? I guess I also do not need the type constraint on the empty method as I have it on the trait.

Comment: @joesan no, it would go on the companion object, it is a factory.